# SSS Shader Not Working! (GLSL)

Tags: glsl

The code below does not work as expected. Increasing scColor RAPIDLY brightens the image, which should not happen. Instead it should simply increase the diffuse effect without brightening or darkening the image at all.

I believe the culprit is the "diffeq" function (comments added):

```
vec4 tally = textureCube(iChannel0,nrm); //initial lookup value behind sphere
vec4 a = abColor+scColor; //coefficient a for differential equation solver
vec4 e = 2.0*emColor+0.5*scColor; //coefficient e for differential equation solver
vec4 retval = e*depth+tally*exp(-a*depth); //solve differential equation
```

The equation in question is the volume rendering equation, which is emmission+inscattering-absorption-outscattering, or the differential equation L<sub>o</sub>'=[k<sub>e</sub>+S-k<sub>a</sub>L<sub>i</sub>-k<sub>s</sub>L<sub>i</sub>]t', where S=k<sub>e</sub>+k<sub>s</sub>∫pL<sub>i</sub>dω. I have attempted to solve the equation, assuming ∫pL<sub>i</sub>dω=0.5. Was this a bad assumption, or is the problem elsewhere?

[Link to Shadertoy Project](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MdGSDK)

Full Code:

```
vec4 abColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
vec4 scColor = vec4(2.0,1.0,4.0,0.0);
vec4 emColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);

vec4 diffeq(vec3 nrm,float depth)
{
    vec4 tally = textureCube(iChannel0,nrm);
    vec4 a = abColor+scColor;
    vec4 e = 2.0*emColor+0.5*scColor;
    vec4 retval = e*depth+tally*exp(-a*depth);
    return retval;
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    fragColor = vec4(0.0);
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    uv = (uv*4.0)-vec2(2.0);
    uv *= vec2(iResolution.x/iResolution.y, 1.0);
    if(length(uv)<1.0)
    {
        vec3 nrm = vec3(uv,-2.0);
        fragColor = diffeq(nrm,2.0*sqrt(1.0-pow(length(uv),2.0)));
    }
    else
    {
        fragColor = textureCube(iChannel0,vec3(uv,-2.0));
    }
}
```

[EDIT]

It seems I have not solved the differential equation correctly, and as such the resulting image is not what I had expected.